# CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME error after edit a function(Updated log file)

Tags: c++, matrix, opencl, gpgpu

The problem is solved (If you're interested ; you can see the second paragraph ; below the line) . Now I have a new question ; why `#define BLOCK_DIM 16;`  cause an error in the function below ?  Just use `16` is fine .

Here are the errors

```
     expected a "]"
      __local float2 block[BLOCK_DIM * (BLOCK_DIM + 1)] ;
                           ^

     line 110: error:
              expected a ")"
      __local float2 block[BLOCK_DIM * (BLOCK_DIM + 1)] ;
                                        ^

     line 110: error: operand
              of "*" must be a pointer
      __local float2 block[BLOCK_DIM * (BLOCK_DIM + 1)] ;

error:
          expected a ";"
          int Idout = get_local_id(0)*(BLOCK_DIM+1)+get_local_id(1);
                                                  ^
```

and the function

```
    __kernel void   transpose(
             __global float2* dataout, 
             __global float2* datain, 
             int width, int height)

// width = N (signal length) 
// height = batch_size (number of signals in a batch)

{
// read the matrix tile into shared memory

__local float2 block[32 * (32 + 1)] ;
   unsigned int xIndex = get_global_id(0);
   unsigned int yIndex = get_global_id(1);

    if((xIndex < width) && (yIndex < height))
    {
            unsigned int index_in = yIndex * width + xIndex;
                       int Idin = get_local_id(1)*(32+1)+get_local_id(0);
                       block[Idin]=  datain[index_in];
    }

barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

// write the transposed matrix tile to global memory

             xIndex = get_group_id(1) * 32 + get_local_id(0);
             yIndex = get_group_id(0) * 32 + get_local_id(1);

    if((xIndex < height) && (yIndex < width))
    {
        unsigned int index_out = yIndex * height + xIndex;
        int Idout = get_local_id(0)*(32+1)+get_local_id(1);
                dataout[index_out] = block[Idout];
    }

}
```

===============================

I'm working to improve the perfomance of a 2D FFT on images . After a benchmark ; I regconize the transpose function is the reason make the program slow , so I replace it with a more optimized one .

But after that ; I received a return code of all the functions which work fine before `CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME`. Except the transpose function and `clSetKernelArg` in the host code ; I don’t change anything else . So I’m out of idea. Hope you guys help me out :)

UPDATE : Here are the errors . Don't mind the line number :) Those lines seems normal with me . Is anything wrong ?

error:

```
     expected a "]"
      __local float2 block[BLOCK_DIM * (BLOCK_DIM + 1)] ;
                           ^

     line 110: error:
              expected a ")"
      __local float2 block[BLOCK_DIM * (BLOCK_DIM + 1)] ;
                                        ^

     line 110: error: operand
              of "*" must be a pointer
      __local float2 block[BLOCK_DIM * (BLOCK_DIM + 1)] ;

error:
          expected a ";"
          int Idout = get_local_id(0)*(BLOCK_DIM+1)+get_local_id(1);
                                                  ^
```

Here is the **[kernel file](http://pastebin.com/SGrJuUac)**

The new one :

```
#define BLOCK_DIM 16

__kernel void   transpose(
             __global float2* dataout, 
             __global float2* datain, 
             int width, int height)

// width = N (signal length) 
// height = batch_size (number of signals in a batch)

{
// read the matrix tile into shared memory

__local float2 block[BLOCK_DIM * (BLOCK_DIM + 1)] ;
   unsigned int xIndex = get_global_id(0);
   unsigned int yIndex = get_global_id(1);

    if((xIndex < width) && (yIndex < height))
    {
            unsigned int index_in = yIndex * width + xIndex;
                       int Idin = get_local_id(1)*(BLOCK_DIM+1)+get_local_id(0);
                       block[Idin]=  datain[index_in];
    }

barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

// write the transposed matrix tile to global memory

             xIndex = get_group_id(1) * BLOCK_DIM + get_local_id(0);
             yIndex = get_group_id(0) * BLOCK_DIM + get_local_id(1);

    if((xIndex < height) && (yIndex < width))
    {
        unsigned int index_out = yIndex * height + xIndex;
        int Idout = get_local_id(0)*(BLOCK_DIM+1)+get_local_id(1);
                dataout[index_out] = block[Idout];
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the compiler give you any warning output? You forgot a semicolon at the declaration of "block" in your second kernel, by the way.

Comment: Thank for the suggestion ; I'm checking the log file right now .

Comment: Your #define question.. they don't require semicolons. Basically, #define X Y will replace all occurrences of "X" with "Y" in the code before being compiled, if you add a semicolon in the end that'll become part of "Y" and create lots of syntax errors. A #define is *not* a statement.

Comment: Thank you . I got it. If you don't mind ; can you write your answer to the "answer section" so I can vote for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your #define question.. they don't require semicolons. Basically, #define X Y will replace all occurrences of "X" with "Y" in the code before being compiled, if you add a semicolon in the end that'll become part of "Y" and create lots of syntax errors. A #define is not a statement.

Actually, that's a simplistic explanation, but it suffices for the scope of this question (if you want to learn more, I recommend you look at preprocessor tutorials and documentation).